# Split numbers in multiple ranges

Tags: python, data-preprocessing

Given the following problem,

```
Input
lis = ['0-10,000, 10,001-11,000, 11,001-12,000']

Output:
['0-10,000','10,001-11,000', '11,001-12,000']
```

Create a function such that, it should avoid if there's a single range in the list but split the ranges if there are multiple ranges in the list.

Can anybody help me with this problem, I can't even think of any method.

Comment: `lis[0].split()`

Comment: Seems like you just want to split on `", "`: `[s.split(', ') for s in lis]`. Or if there's really just one element in the list: `lis[0].split(", ")`

Comment: But there's an unnecessary `,` at the end of every range in the output. Example output: `['0-10,000,', '10,001-11,000,', '11,001-12,000']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build a string from the list of elements, then split the string with the specified ", ".

```
lis = ['0-10,000, 10,001-11,000, 11,001-12,000']

print(''.join(lis).split(", "))
```

Comment: Casting is not a python term. You can build a string from the elements of the list, or you can join them into a string, but casting is meaningless in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this :

```
lis = ['0-10,000, 10,001-11,000, 11,001-12,000','0-10,001, 10,001-11,000, 11,001-12,000','0-10,011, 10,001-11,000, 11,001-12,000']
 
def data_clean(x):
  v = []
  for i in range(len(x)):
    v.append(x[i].split(", "))   
  return v
```

Here it is how the output is :

```
[['0-10,000', '10,001-11,000', '11,001-12,000'],
 ['0-10,001', '10,001-11,000', '11,001-12,000'],
 ['0-10,011', '10,001-11,000', '11,001-12,000']]
```